# How to get parent event inside ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to invoke a Command from view model inside radio button `ControlTemplate`. And do it when event `Checked` is raised

I tried this:

```xaml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RequestTypeControlTemplate" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <!-- Checked event from parent -->
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                    <!-- Command from view model and binding to tag of radio button as arg -->
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OnTypeChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But I think event goes from ContentPresenter, not from RadioButton. How do I get the event from RadioButton?

EDIT:

```
 <RadioButton Content="All requests"
                                 ContentTemplate="{StaticResource RadioButtonDataTemplate}"
                                 GroupName="Filter"
                                 IsChecked="True"
                                 Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                                 Template="{StaticResource RequestTypeControlTemplate}"
                                 Tag="{x:Static local:ContentType.Any}"/>
```

In viewModel

```
  public ICommand OnTypeChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TypeChangedCommand ?? (m_TypeChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<ContentType>(OnTypeChanged));
        }
    }

    public void OnTypeChanged(ContentType type)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(type);
    }
```

Comment: check if you reach the getter with a break point.

Comment: Tried getter, works normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because the Routed event is only handled from the element (bubble) or to the element (tunnel)

What you can use is a DataTrigger on IsChecked property .

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"  

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton}}" Value=True>
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OnTypeChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton}}}" />       
    </ei:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: How can i call method from Trigger?

Comment: IsChecked should be my property in viewModel?

Comment: Because if not i have BindingExpression path error: 'IsChecked' property not found on 'object' ''DataTrigger'

Comment: No need to apologize, you are helping me) I see no errors now, but it doesn't work. OnTypeChangedCommand doesn't invoked